# What is the common name for mapping one range of numbers maps to another range of numbers?

Tags: function, math, naming

I'm pretty sure it's a common pattern, but I'm looking for the name of the pattern where you match one range of numbers to another range of numbers. Something similar like:

```
Map(from1: 60, to1: 90, from2: 100, to2: 140, value: 75);  // Result: 120 (middle of from2/to2)
Map(from1: 60, to1: 90, from2: 100, to2: 140, value: 30);  // Result: 100 (clamped bottom)
Map(from1: 60, to1: 90, from2: 100, to2: 140, value: 60);  // Result: 100 (bottom)
Map(from1: 60, to1: 90, from2: 100, to2: 140, value: 500); // Result: 140 (clamped to2)
Map(from1: 60, to1: 90, from2: 100, to2: 140, value: 85);  // Result: 133.33 (in between)
```

What is the name for this method? I'm specifically looking for a solution in Unity, but I'm pretty sure if I know the name of the pattern I can find it.

[image]

Comment: I'd call this linear interpolation. [`numpy.interp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html), which describes itself as doing "piecewise linear interpolation", has exactly the behaviour you describe, including the clamping, in the case where `len(xp) == len(fp) == 2`. E.g. `numpy.interp(85, [60, 90], [100, 140])` -> `133.33333333333331`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah never mind - I found it in a Unreal Engine tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11T4UvkVYb8

The term used here is MapRangeClamped and MapRangeUnclamped.

Here is the code for C#:

```
public static class FloatExtensions
{
    public static float MapRange(this float value, float from1, float to1, float from2, float to2, bool clamp = false) 
    {
        if ( clamp )
        {
            if ( value < from1 )
                return from2;
            if ( value > to1 )
                return to2;
        }

        return (value - from1) / (to1 - from1) * (to2 - from2) + from2;
    }
}
```